# Getting ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0) in python celery

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to run simple task in celery. According to the need I have to add the tasks in queue and get their task_id and then later I have to execute the task using that task_id.

I tried this code but getting following error

**Error on terminal**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 361, in workloop
    result = (True, prepare_result(fun(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 664, in fast_trace_task
    tasks, accept, hostname = _loc
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

Error stored in **mongodb celery_taskmeta**

```
{  "_id": "537073b1-e758-4315-b386-31a2c62b3b45",  "status": "FAILURE",  "result": "{\"exc_type\": \"ValueError\", \"exc_message\": [\"not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)\"], \"exc_module\": \"builtins\"}",  "traceback": null,  "children": [],  "date_done": "2023-08-31T06:13:37.776662"}
```

**code**
**main.py**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery("main", broker="amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672", backend="mongodb://localhost:27017/celery")

@app.task
def add():
    return 3+4
```

I am running main.py using following command

```
celery -A main worker --loglevel=info
```

**executor.py**

```
from main import add
from celery.result import AsyncResult

result = add.apply_async()

task_id = result.id
print("Task ID:", task_id)

task_result = AsyncResult(task_id)

if task_result.ready():
    result_value = task_result.get()
    print("Task Result:", result_value)
else:
    print("Task is still processing")
```

I am getting the task_id and Task is still processing is getting printed. But the status of the task is failure due to the error

getting same error when using delay() and get()

```
from main import add

result = add.delay(3,4)

task_result = result.get()

print("Task Result:", task_result)
```

Comment: Yeah @eten `celery -A my_project_name worker --pool=solo -l info` this command from the forum is working for me. Thank you